# Before insert trigger for WordPress MySQL database, #1064 & #1054 error

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to create a trigger for a WordPress MySQL database that changes post_status to 'inherited' seven days after the insert statement happens. However, executing this code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `changeStatus` BEFORE INSERT
    ON `wp_posts`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF post_type='product' THEN
    set NEW.post_status = 'inherited'
    WHERE OLD.post_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
    END IF;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

results in an "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE OLD.post_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY); END IF; END' at line 7" error.

Furthermore, reducing the trigger to:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE
        TRIGGER `changeStatus` BEFORE INSERT
        ON `wp_posts`
        FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF post_type='product' THEN
        set NEW.post_status = 'inherited';
        END IF;
        END$$
        DELIMITER ;
```

does, in fact, create a new trigger, but inserting values into wp_posts results in an "#1054 - Unknown column 'post_type' in 'field list'" error.

What is the culprit? Any help will be greatly appreciated since I'm completely new to WordPress and MySQL. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which `post_type` ? `OLD.post_type` or `NEW.post_type`? `SET` stynax doesn't have a `WHERE` however you can do nested `IF` statements or  you might be able to do an `IF ... AND ... THEN`

Comment: When i use old.post_type in the if statement and try to execute the query, I get
 "#1363 - There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger". 

After removing the line of code with WHERE statement and modyfing the IF statement to 

IF post_type='product' AND post_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN

the trigger is created, but I still cannot insert anything into wp_posts (again, #1054 error mentioned above pops up)

Comment: I don't think a trigger is appropriate for what you are trying to do. Perhaps an event would be https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

Answer (score 0):

Before insert the OLD Value must be an `old.post_type`

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE
        TRIGGER `changeStatus` BEFORE INSERT
        ON `wp_posts`
        FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF old.post_type='product' THEN
        set NEW.post_status = 'inherited';
        END IF;
     END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

This Code means:

```
IF old.post_type='product' THEN
set NEW.post_status = 'inherited';
```

if true(`post_type='product'`) then `NEW.post_status = 'inherited';`

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in an "#1363 - There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger" error.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, however, after swapping old.post_type with new.post_type, the trigger does its job like it was designed to. Thanks a bunch for helping me out!

Comment: `new.post_type` Means a new Data try to change `After Insert` for Simulation.

Comment: After changing BEFORE to AFTER i get the same error #1363, unfortunately.